Fields in Scala Constructor
I was wondering if there are any differences between the two following class implementations:
class Days(days:AnyVal):
    val n: AnyVal = days

and
class Days(val n:AnyVal)

Does n has the same accessibility in both classes? Any other differences?

Yeah the first one is just a more boilerplate way to do the second thing. BTW, using AnyVal is almost always a bad idea.

Thank you for your reply! And yes I figured it is a bad idea, indeed I changed it. I am trying to do a Scala exercises where I am creating class Weeks , class Days , and class Hours and being able to do operations with them such val weeks: Weeks = Weeks(5) + Days(2) If you do have any tips for this kind of exercise I'd appreciate it! Thanks

Uhm yeah write an ADT and a custom + using pattern matching. You also may just defer to already existing date types.

You may benefit from using case classes instead https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html

Great! Thank you all. I know there are libraries to do so but I am doing this merely as an exercise to learn Scala.
